# What this over mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> She was sitting there one afternoon in early June. The sun was coming in at the window warm and bright; the orchard on the slope below the house was in a bridal flush of pinky-white bloom, hummed ***over*** by a myriad of bees. Thomas Lynde—a meek little man whom Avonlea people called "Rachel Lynde's husband"—was sowing his late turnip seed on the hill field beyond the barn; and Matthew Cuthbert ought to have been sowing his on the big red brook field away over by Green Gables.
>
> -- L. M. Montgomery, Anne of Green Gables

What does over mean? (I guess over has two possibility: (1) over the orchard - vertically upward; horizontally from here to there, (2) all sounds are drowned because of the bees’ humming.)

Comment: This is lovely! I can almost see her orchard right in front of my face, at its full blooming, countless of bees humming over the orchard! What a vivid and beautiful sight to see!

Comment: Your second guess is the correct one, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its most basic level, *over* can be taken to signify spatial position, ‘above’. But *hummed over* is an unusual and quite complex construction.

In the first place, *over* in the context of bees and flowers suggests not merely elevation but distribution: the bees do not hover above the flowers but are to be found within and across them—“all over” them.

In the second place, *over* with an activity verb like *hum* suggests comparison with similar *VERB over* phrases. Nurses *watch over* the children in their charge, scholars *pore over* ancient manuscripts, a chairman *presides over* a meeting. To come closer to *hum*, a mother *sings over* her child's cradle, a priest *chants over* the sacrifice, customers *ooh and ahh over* a spectacular display of merchandise.

All of these evoke a sense of close and purposeful attention; and that is emphasized, I think, by the passive form in which *hum over* is cast. To me, the phrase strongly suggests that the flowers are being *tended* by the bees, who are actively pursuing their agricultural purposes in the same way as Lynde is pursuing his.

The phrase suggests that Cuthbert’s failure to sow *his* turnips is not merely out of character but a sort of breach in the natural order.